# Hi I am confused with the following sentence "Vijay Mallya, declared a proclaimed offender in a money laundering case"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, sentence-meaning, indian-english

In the above sentence Vijay Mallya is declaring any other person as an offender or vijay malya is declared as an offender I didn't understand and please can anybody explain me clearly and some suggestions on how to improve my readabality.

Comment: Is that exactly what the text said? Are you sure you copied correctly?

Comment: Hi @probablyme this is exact "Vijay Mallya, declared a proclaimed offender in a money laundering case, on Sunday said he was not a “gate crasher” since we cannot post more than 150 characters in question dialog box thats why I reduced and this sentenced I saw In THE HINDU

Comment: I see. No, that is not the "question dialog", it is for the title. You can add many, or better yet, all the details in the **main body** of the post. Yes, you have to keep the title brief, but add all the details in the body. This will prevent some confusion.

Comment: Headline from [The Hindu, June 14:](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/vijaya-mallya-declared-proclaimed-offender/article8728455.ece) *Court declares Mallya a proclaimed offender*. Obviously "proclaimed offender" is a two-word noun with some special legal significance. In fact, the text of that article continues with *A person is termed a **proclaimed offender** in a criminal investigation if the court believes that the accused has absconded or is concealing himself so that a warrant cannot be executed.* The court has classified Mallya as one of those - that's all there is to it.

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggestion @probablyme please can you explain me the meaning of the sentence

Comment: Hi @ FumbleFingers http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/vijay-mallya-says-hes-not-a-gatecrasher-after-london-book-event-row/article8748529.ece?ref=sliderNews please check this link its jun19news and the headline is different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Vijay Mallya, declared a proclaimed offender in a money laundering case".Means here Vijay Mallya is a noun and after that followed by comma the remaining sentence is there and it seems to be like VIjay malya declared some one as an offneder thats what the confusion starts for me

Comment: @CSiva: The *syntax* is exactly the same in both cases. Is there something else you don't understand, apart from the fact that it looks a little odd to *declare [someone] a proclaimed offender*? The legal term "proclaimed offender" is somewhat arbitrary (I've never heard of it before), so in principle it could have been "declared offender" - in which case your text *might* have used the noun phrase *Vijay Mallya, **proclaimed a declared offender** in a money laundering case*. Do you understand that?

Comment: It's the same as *Jo Cox, **elected [as] a British MP last year,** was murdered*. The highlighted clause is a "passive" construction - Jo Cox didn't elect anyone or anything; it was the (unspecified) *voters* who elected ***her***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your answer it helped me.Now I understood clearly.

Comment: It's important to note that the cited text in the question is *not* a "sentence" - it's just a ***noun phrase***. My Jo Cox example above *is* a complete sentence, since it contains the "verb" component ***was murdered***.

Answer (score 1):

Note this headline from [The Hindu, June 14](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/vijaya-mallya-declared-proclaimed-offender/article8728455.ece)...

> *Court declares Mallya a proclaimed offender*

Although I'd never heard of a "proclaimed offender" before, the context of that headline makes it obvious it's a two-word noun with some special legal significance. In fact, the text of that article continues with...

> *A person is termed a "**proclaimed offender**" in a criminal investigation if the court believes that the accused has absconded or is concealing himself so that a warrant cannot be executed.*

...where I've added the quote marks and highlighting for clarity. Bear in mind that the verbs ***to declare*** and ***to proclaim*** are effectively synonyms, and it's really a matter of chance that the Indian legal system chose to use *"**proclaimed offender**"* rather than *"**declared offender**"* for their purpose. If they'd chosen the other term, the headline might easily have been...

> *Court **proclaims** [that] Mallya [is] a **declared offender***

...which is syntactically just as valid, but doesn't use the established legal terminology.

---

Also note that *Vijay Mallya, declared a proclaimed offender in a money laundering case* is a *noun phrase* (a potential *subject*, but with no functional verb). It's not a complete sentence - that would be something like...

> *Mallya, a proclaimed offender, insists [that] he is innocent.*